# named query showing wrong ticketstatusname in ssas cube

Tags: ssas, ticket-system

i have written named query in that query i have attributes like request_id,createddate,confirmeddate, reporteddate,sitename,ticketstatusname etc.....

i want to know ticketstatusname for request_id's i.e open or closed. i have filtered date as ReportedDate='2011-07-31 00:00:00.000' for particular date i want to know how many request_id's are in open and how many are closed for each site.for example sitename='BOUZ' that containing 25 request_id's are open and 225 request_id's are closed. same query i have copied and past in ssas cube and i processed when i drag and drop sitename,ticketstatusname into cube browser i am getting count correctly but ticketstatusname i am getting wrong i.e actually closed tickets are showing in open status. plese can you help why i am getting wrong status for request)id's in my ssas cube. Following is the named query.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT d.Short_sitename AS Sitename,
          f.Request_ID,
          dt3.FullDateAlternateKey AS CreatedDate,
          dt2.FullDateAlternateKey AS ConfirmedDate,
          dt1.FullDateAlternateKey AS ReportedDate,
          CASE
              WHEN (dt2.FullDateAlternateKey IS NULL)
                   OR (dt1.FullDateAlternateKey<dt2.FullDateAlternateKey) THEN 'Open'
              ELSE 'Closed'
          END AS TicketStatusName,
   FROM FactTicket AS f
   LEFT OUTER JOIN DimTime AS dt3 ON dt3.TimeKey = f.Create_DateKey
   LEFT OUTER JOIN DimTime AS dt2 ON dt2.TimeKey = f.Confirmed_DateKey
   LEFT OUTER JOIN DimSite AS d ON d.Site_ID=f.Site_ID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN DimTime AS dt1 ON dt1.FullDateAlternateKey BETWEEN dt3.FullDateAlternateKey AND DATEADD(d, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, ISNULL(dt2.FullDateAlternateKey, GETDATE())) + (12 - MONTH(ISNULL(dt2.FullDateAlternateKey, GETDATE())) + 1), 0))
   WHERE (dt1.FullDateAlternateKey = DATEADD(d, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, dt1.FullDateAlternateKey) + 1, 0)))
     AND (f.Type_ID1 IS NOT NULL)
     AND (f.Type_ID2 IS NOT NULL)
     AND (f.Type_ID3 IS NOT NULL) )A
WHERE ReportedDate='2011-07-31 00:00:00.000'
  AND sitename='BOUZ'
```